# Is “recordee” a word?

Tags: vocabulary, suffixes, is-it-a-word, er-ee

Does *recordee* exist in English? The word doesn't exist in Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries, but I was hoping to use it as "someone who is being recorded".

Comment: By your logic, the word "recorder" would then mean "someone who is recording".

Comment: I doubt you'll find it in any *dictionaries*, but [here are a few dozen written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+Recordee%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) of **the recordee**. It's regularly-formed, and in context the meaning should be obvious. It's just a matter of opinion whether you count it as a "word".

Comment: Words created through productive derivational morphology do not have to be listed in a dictionary, and in fact, all of them never are so.  This is a constant mistake learners make, thinking that dictionaries contain all the words of a language. They don’t, not even the OED.

Comment: ... Whereas other people make the mistake of assuming that any string of letters ever written down qualifies as a word. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicon): Linguistic theories generally regard human languages as consisting of two parts: a lexicon, essentially a catalogue of a language's words ... A central role of the lexicon is the documenting of established lexical norms and conventions. Lexicalization is the process where new words, having gained ... widespread usage, enter in[to] the lexicon.

Comment: If I play the recorder, does that make me a recordee?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, but it might make you a recorderer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  Wictictionary:  [recordee](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/recordee): (plural recordees)

> - One who is recorded.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recordee&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecordee%3B%2Cc0) shows that is  a very rare term.

> - It is important to have such texts orthographically transcribed by a native speaker, **preferably the recordees themselves**, as this is an almost indispensable aid to phonetic transcription and subsequent segmentation.

Comment: Haha - your post appeared just as I was commenting above. But putting aside the question of whether Wiktionary counts as a "dictionary", obviously if people want to use **recordee** with OP's sense, there's nothing particularly unusual about it. If you had any doubts, you could always put the term in "scare quotes" to alert the reader that he might need to tax a brain cell or two, in order to understand the intended meaning.

Comment: I am not suggesting it is a 'usable' term, and Ngram evidence is quite clear about its usage. :).

Comment: Actually, in this particular case, the NGram tells us next to nothing. I was surprised there were even enough instances to graph - but if you check the actual instances, most of them aren't relevant (OCR errors, French texts, etc.). Nevertheless, unless we're going to get bogged down in futile discussion about "What is a word?", even half-a-dozen valid usages would be quite enough to justify the designation in this case. And there are definitely many more than that.

Comment: @FF Brilliant usage-definition of 'scare quotes'. (Which term appears in that marvellous dictionary, er ...)

Answer (score 3):

It might be of interest that *ee* is a productive suffix in English. This means you can use it in situations that it has never been used in before. It will still be grammatical and easily understood. It is straightforwardly formed by adding *ee* to the base form of a transitive verb to form a noun.

The referent of the noun is understood as a/the person whom the action indicated by the verb was or is done to (in other words they would be considered to have the thematic role of *patient* in relation to said verb). Because it's a productive suffix, it isn't possible to put all such possible words with this affix into a dictionary - even if this one does actually appear in a few of them. Most importantly, you don't need to worry how frequent this is, or even whether anyone has ever said it before - it is still correct!

Answer (score 1):

The 'recordee' is more commonly referred to as the '[subject (1.2)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subject)', '[target](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/target)' or 'the do-er-of-recorded-matter' (actor/player/musician etc).